# SQL Server 2005 CLR function System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: sql-server-2005

My coworker wrote a package in VB.NET to manipulate strings. I have been asked to implement them through CLR. The package accesses a reference database on the same server as the CLR dll file deployed to standardize the strings. I imported the package to my CLR code to create the functions for SQL Server.

After I deploy the dll file to sql server, the functions work fine except occasionally I get the error

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I have to execute my query several times to make it work. It seems the table is locked or sleeping. My query is like

***SELECT*** EMAIL_ADDRESS, dbo.ufn_getEmailDomain(Email_Address) ***AS*** EDOMAIN ***FROM*** CONTACT_TEMP
        ***WHERE*** Email_Address IS NOT NULL AND Email_Address<>''

dbo.ufn_getEmailDomain is the CLR function.

There is no online access to this server at all.  I searched for a while and couldn't find why this error comes up occasionally or how to fix it.

Your feedback is greatly appreciated.

**my CLR functions here.**

```
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess:=DataAccessKind.Read)> _
Public Shared Function ufn_getEmailDomainSLD(ByVal email As String) As String

    If email Is Nothing Then
        Return Nothing
    End If

    Dim de As New DataEmail(email)
    Dim dm As New DataDomain
    Dim emailDomain As String
    dm = de.Domain

    emailDomain = dm.SLD

    Return emailDomain
End Function
```

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` is a bug in your `.NET` code trying to call a method or property on an object variable that is null. Please provide the definition of the class containing `ufn_getEmailDomain`

Comment: Also there is no guarantee that the `WHERE` clause will be processed before the function call. Can you reproduce this error by passing in `NULL` or empty string?

Comment: Martin, I added my CLR function on the top. I tried call the function with null or empty string and it works fine. I have a SP that uses this function to update a field. Sometimes it runs fine. Sometime, this error comes up.

Comment: Hmm, Not many clues there. Doesn't it give you a stack trace so you can identify which specific line the error is being thrown on?

Comment: Martin, by the way I think select part is the part processed last, how come you say there is no guarantee that the WHERE clause will be processed before the function call?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this error now. It just happens occasionally like I mentioned below. If I don't use this function for several days, this error comes up.

Comment: for the `SELECT ... WHERE` question [see the examples here](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason eventually. In the connection string in the CLR code, I should set ENLIST=FALSE because it connects to a different database. Once I set ENLIST=FALSE, the problem seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right - function returns domain name from email string.

Try to get it in such a way (if there are not milti-mail string values)

```
SELECT 
  EMAIL_ADDRESS, 
  SUBSTRING(EMAIL_ADDRESS, CHARINDEX('@', Item)+1, 2147483647) AS EDOMAIN 
FROM CONTACT_TEMP 
WHERE Email_Address IS NOT NULL AND Email_Address<>''
```

**and** - find your bug in your clr code. Try to recreate function with option `RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT`. If it is not help - then you need to review and to clean your CLR code.

Comment: Now I cannot even reproduce this error. It just comes up occasionally, especially if I don't use this functions for several days. This function parses very complicated domain, that's why my boss wants me to implement it to SQL.